# Run a command as root on startup

Tags: rc.local

I  need to run this command line at startup:

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
```

When I go to terminal type SU enter my password type that command it works perfectly, yet when I add that line to `/etc/rc.local` before the exit 0 it does nothing at all.

I am running Raspian on a Raspberry pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a kernel module parameter, so the best way to set that is by creating a file in `/etc/modprobe.d`.  E.g., create `/etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf` with the contents:

```
options bluetooth disable_ertm=1
```

Reboot your system, and check that `/sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm` looks as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a systemd service to run a bash script containing the command:

```
[Unit]
Description=disable_ertm
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/path/to/bash/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Actual Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
```

Or add to rc.local like:

```
sudo update-rc.d /path/to/bash/script defaults
```

Make sure it is chmod +x.